# Highcharts send global data to angular controller

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I've recently decided to use angular on a webpage, but having never used it before and being new to web dev I've run into some issues. The page has some highchart graphs where, upon clicking on a point triggers a modal with a table of data. This table is created with an angular controller.

Initially the table is empty because the user hasn't selected the data to populate it. So the data called: `cases` starts:`var cases = [];` and the controller initializes with: `$scope.items = cases;`

Here is where I get the data for the table:

```
plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function () {
                                if (this.series.name == 'Work left')
                                {
                                    cases = [];
                                    //GET THE DATA
                                    $.getJSON(uri + '/get?team=' + team + '&sprint=' + sprint + '&day=' + this.category)
                                     .done(function (data) {
                                         $.each(data, function (n, field) {
                                             n++
                                             cases.push({ "DT": field.dt, "Title": field.subject, "Type": field.type, "Est": field.est, "Product": field.Prod, "Sprint": field.Sprint, "Status": field.Status, "CreatedDate": field.cDate });
                                         });
                                     });
                                    //UPDATE THE TABLE WITH NEW DATA HERE
                                    $("#myModal").modal();//TRIGGER MODAL
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

In this highchart function I get the parameters: `team`,`sprint` and `day` based off of which point on which graph the user clicked. Then get the data from an api call.

What I want to know is if it's possible to "reinitialize" the angular controller at `//UPDATE THE TABLE WITH NEW DATA HERE` line, before triggering the modal. I need `$scope.items = cases;` but with `cases` being populated with the new data.

Basically I get the data dynamically with a highchart function, and I want to send this data to the angular controller where the table is updated, so that when I trigger the modal the table on it has the specified data.

Angular table controller:

```
var sortingOrder = 'CreatedDate'; //default sort
var app = angular.module("casetable", []);

app.controller('initApp', ['$scope', '$filter',
function ($scope, $filter) {
    // init
    $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.filteredItems = [];
    $scope.groupedItems = [];
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 9;
    $scope.pagedItems = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.items = cases;

    var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
        if (!needle) {
            return true;
        }
        return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    };

    // init the filtered items
    $scope.search = function () {
        $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
            for (var attr in item) {
                if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        // take care of the sorting order
        if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
            $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, $scope.reverse);
        }
        $scope.currentPage = 0;
        // now group by pages
        $scope.groupToPages();
    };

    // show items per page
    $scope.perPage = function () {
        $scope.groupToPages();
    };

    // calculate page in place
    $scope.groupToPages = function () {
        $scope.pagedItems = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
            if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)] = [$scope.filteredItems[i]];
            } else {
                $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.deleteItem = function (idx) {
        var itemToDelete = $scope.pagedItems[$scope.currentPage][idx];
        var idxInItems = $scope.items.indexOf(itemToDelete);
        $scope.items.splice(idxInItems, 1);
        $scope.search();

        return false;
    };

    $scope.range = function (start, end) {
        var ret = [];
        if (!end) {
            end = start;
            start = 0;
        }
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            ret.push(i);
        }
        return ret;
    };

    $scope.prevPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
            $scope.currentPage--;
        }
    };

    $scope.nextPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
        }
    };

    $scope.setPage = function () {
        $scope.currentPage = this.n;
    };

    // functions have been describe process the data for display
    $scope.search();


    // change sorting order
    $scope.sort_by = function (newSortingOrder) {
        if ($scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

        $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Where are you calling the Highcharts code?

Comment: Have you seen [the official Highcharts article about working with AngularJS](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js)?

Comment: @morecchia808 It gets called after the angular code

Comment: @KacperMadej Looks helpful, but I'd have to rewrite everything. I just want to know if my approach is possible.

Comment: @daeddy I think the root of your problem is that you are not calling Highcharts in the context of angular, so you will have difficulty binding your data to angular's $scope.  You should try creating the Highchart in an angular service, then injecting it into your controller so you can share the data coming in from your API. Also - use angular's $http service instead of $.getJSON.

Comment: @morecchia808 Yeah I've decided to go in that direction. Its just gonna be a lot of work. I would've liked to be able to use what I already had...